# hide the background image when the hover image appears using css

Tags: html, css, hover

I am using CSS for hover and it works, but the hover image  allow the background image (`pic_normal`) to display like transparent behind the  image(`pic_hover`).

How to display only the hover image when mouse over on it?

***HTML***

```
<img id="first" src="images/clients/pic_normal.png" />
```

***CSS***

```css
#first img:hover {
    background-image: url("/images/clients/pic_hover.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: check my answer i have post a single line for doing it....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CSS works just fine as intended - it changes the background of your `img` element. Think about the `pic_normal.png` as the content of your element (e.gg. some text). When you changing the background the content doesn't change.

Try this instead - http://jsfiddle.net/WvKye/

```
<div id="first"></div>

#first {
    background: url("images/clients/pic_normal.png") no-repeat;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}

#first:hover {
    background: url("images/clients/pic_hover.png") no-repeat;
}​
```

Comment: :so, instead of setting id for <img> i use <div> to overcome my issue?

Comment: Yes, its' the best way to do it. If you want to use the `<img>` you have to use JS or jQuery(as __Akhil__ suggested), which is slightly less reliable (if you think about those who have disabled JS)

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
<img onMouseOver="this.src='images/clients/pic_normal.png'"
 onMouseOut="this.src='images/clients/pic_normal.png'"
 src="images/clients/pic_normal.png"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think u need some javascript for that
Using Jquery u can do like this

```
$("#first").hover(function()
{
 $(this).attr("src","/images/clients/pic_hover.png");
},function()
{
  $(this).attr("src","/images/clients/pic_normal.png");
}
);
```